# How can I convert this cURL command to PHP?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, ssh

The SSH command I'm currently using in Terminal is:

```
curl -L -b cookies.txt http://www.dropbox.com/s/8lu0nutt4tgpkku/jbtools.ipa -o iOS9_beta.ipsw
```

I first login to my developer account and then download the cookies by a Chrome extension; following that, I upload the cookies.txt file to the same path I run the SSH command and easily mirror the file to my server.
Now, I would like to do the same job with a PHP script. I tried this code but didn't work.

```
<?php
$cSession = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.dropbox.com/s/8lu0nutt4tgpkku/jbtools.ipa");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
echo $result;
?>
```

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:
I updated my code the below code but:

1. If I use CURLOPT_USERPWD option I get "401 Authorization Required" although I define the correct user&pass
2. If I use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option I get "403 Forbidden" although the cookies.txt is not expired!

[The live Link](http://i-0s.ir/tst.php)

```
$cSession = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://adcdownload.apple.com/Safari/Safari_10_for_OS_X_El_Capitan_and_Yosemite_beta_5/Safari_10_for_OS_X_El_Capitan_beta_5.dmg");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "MyUser:MyPass");
// curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
//curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
echo $result;
```

Comment: `"I tried this code but didn't work."` How didn't it work? Were there any errors? Help us help you here ;-)

Comment: No error messages at all. Just a blank page: http://i-0s.ir/MyUD_ir/tst2.php

Comment: The link you are sharing says "unauthorized". Please add more information to help others understand where you are stuck.

Comment: I got this message once I added the new line mentioned in the below answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look whats missing in your curl.

-L = follow redirects

```
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

see:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Just added this line. 401 Authorization Required!