# How to display cURL progress bar in browser (using PHP exec() function)

Tags: php, curl, command-line, terminal, verbose

I'm using this tiny PHP code in order to mirror any files into my server.

```
<?php
 $cmd= "curl -L -O http://www.dropbox.com/s/8lu0nutt4tgpkku/jbtools.ipa";
 exec($cmd);
?>
```

But the browser is freezing until the mirroring process gets finished. My question is that how can I display the progress bar like when I run this command in Terminal. something like this:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

I tried many flags such as:

```
-v --verbose -I -include --trace -
```

but none of them worked. I also asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427001/how-can-i-convert-this-curl-command-to-php) to convert it to a PHP CURL code but no one could help me with that!

If it's not possible, it's really appreciated advising me to do the same job by any other commands.

Comment: Use ob_flush() to send data to browser before loading content is finished, alternatively, you could write the status into a session and access it trough another page. See php.net for a real php curl function. Your code is more a workaround and not good if you want to work with it in php

Comment: I did try cURL but I got stuck at a point but no one could help me!
Can u have a look pleae?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427001/how-can-i-convert-this-curl-command-to-php

Comment: The code looks fine. I cannot find adcdownload.com.

Comment: That link is no longer valid. Just updated the post;check it out pls. BTW, I'm using "-b cookies.txt" for Apple developer portal(for authentication) so as the new link is a Dropbox link, I think we don't need to have this flag!

Comment: As i already told you, i cannot find any mistake. Whats the error the code trows?

Comment: Just UPDATED the first post of that topic along with the link of the code. Can u check it out and advise me from that topic pls.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is by polling. 
Execute the script in the background and direct the output (to a file) that your frontend (js) can poll.

execute in the background with examples:
https://felixmilea.com/2014/12/running-bash-commands-background-properly/

showing progress in the shell can be done with piping to pv:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv

consider trying this with websockets:
http://reactphp.org/   - look at the rachet project. 
this will give you realtime output of whatever you want to execute.